# Set context to request when the later is initialised with a url.URL

Tags: http, go, request, go-context

I want to create a `net/url.URL` and then use it in `http.Client` and `http.Request` constructs as follows

```golang
    client := http.Client{
        Timeout: 5 * time.Second,
    }
    req := http.Request{
        URL: someKindOf_url.URL_type_I_have_already_initialised_elsewhere,
    }
    resp, err := client.Do(&req)
```

Upon `req` construction, I want to pass an (already existing) `context.Context`

The `Request` [type](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request) does not seem to have such a field.

There is this `NewRequestWithContext` factory [function](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#NewRequestWithContext), but uses a string for the `URL` and not a `net/url.URL`

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never create an `http.Request` object with a literal. Always use the constructor functions `NewRequest` or `NewRequestWithContext`. The constructor [does a lot more](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.7:src/net/http/request.go;l=853) than simply assigning simple values to a struct.

With this in mind, the correct way to achieve your goal would be, for example:

```golang
req := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, someKindOf_url.String(), nil)
```

That said, you can assign a context to an existing request:

```golang
req = req.WithContext(ctx)
```

Comment: The problem is my `net/url.URL` has additional info and I am trying to figure out how to pass this to the request  `url: &url.URL{
   Scheme: "https",
   Host:   host,
   User:   url.UserPassword(username, password),
  },`

Comment: I told you how to do that:  `url.String()`. I'm not sure what else you would want. A URL is _just_ a string, after all (albeit with specific semantic meaning). You can't have any part of a URL that can't be represented as a string.

Comment: That will also pass the basic auth found in `url.UserPassword` field?

Comment: Yes. That's part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

`http.Request` doen't have a public context field, but have it private.

What you can do is use `WithContext(ctx context.Context)` method of `http.Request`